# Returning Scope_Identity from 2 insert statements simultaneously in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having problem with my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Project] 
    @Code as nvarChar(255) = null,
    @Id as nvarChar(255) = null,
    @Status as nvarChar(max) = null,
    @Project as nvarChar(max) = null,
    @ClientSystem as nvarchar(max) = null,
    @UserId as bigint = 0,
    @ProjectId as bigint = 0,
    @ProjectDetailsId bigint = 0 Output
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Code]
                   FROM [dbo].[Project]
                   WHERE Project.Code = @Code)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Project]([Code], [Id], [Status], [Project])
        VALUES(@Code, @Id, @Status, @Project)

        SELECT @ProjectId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProjectDetails]([FK_ProjectId], [ClientSystem], [UserId])
        VALUES(@ProjectId, @ClientSystem, @UserId)

        SELECT @ProjectDetailsId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
     END
     ELSE
     BEGIN
        SELECT [ProjectId] AS 'ProjectId'
        FROM [dbo].[Project]
        WHERE Project.Code = @Code
     END
```

I want to return `Scope_Identity` from both `Insert` statements and pass the values of first insert as parameter to 2nd Insert and return the `Scope_Identity` of 2nd Insert statement also.

I am getting error is when I get the identity of first `Insert`, the identity in the specific table increases 2 times like in db table it will be inserted 2 but in coding it will return 1. And that return when i pass to other insert it s giving conflict.

Comment: your code looks ok to me for insert except that your `@ProjectId as bigint = 0,` is not `output` parameter

Comment: @ughai no that is not the reason. The reason is that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the value of the last insert, regardless of where it takes place. So, when a second insert is running **parallel**, then the call to `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will return the value from the other parallel running procedure.

Comment: @ughai no no. It is a known problem. The only correct way is the `OUTPUT` clause. Microsoft has stated this: https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2019779

Comment: @SQLPolice -  It's related to parallel execution plan of the query itself and not related to *"second insert is running parallel"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** Instead of using `SCOPE IDENTITY()`, you need to make use of he `OUTPUT`clause of the `INSERT` statement, like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Project]([Code], [Id], [Status], [Project])
OUTPUT inserted.ID into @ProjectID
SELECT ...
```

**Explanation:** `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the value of the last `insert`, regardless where the insert takes place. So, when when another `insert` is running in **parallel**, then your call to `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will return the value from the **other parallel running procedure**. This then leads to an error.

However, the usage of the `OUTPUT` clause will **guarantee** to return the value from the current `INSERT`.

Here is an interesting article regarding `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and parallel plans:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/24/sql-server-2008-scope_identity-bug-with-multi-processor-parallel-plan-and-solution/

Comment: @SeanLange You are wrong. Even Pinal Dave corrected himself two years later. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/24/sql-server-2008-scope_identity-bug-with-multi-processor-parallel-plan-and-solution/

Comment: hmmmm interesting. 6 years and somehow I managed to miss this one. I stand corrected and will delete my previous incorrect statement. I would retract my downvote but can't unless the answer is edited.

Comment: @SeanLange OK! Would be nice if you removed the downvote, also ;) I can remember that I fell above the problem myself, and some trigger produced errors. But don't know the details right now.

Comment: I would retract my downvote but unless the answer is edited I can't. Given my previous egregious error I didn't feel making an edit for that purpose. If you edit it I will remove it. :D

Answer (score 0):

You need use OUTPUT clause at the procedure parameter

```
@ProjectId as bigint = 0 output,
```

Comment: no that is not the reason. The reason is that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the value of the last insert, regardless of where it takes place. So, when a second insert is running **parallel**, then the call to `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will return the value from the other parallel running procedure.