# SQL Return Inserted Data

Tags: sql-server

I want to select back the data I just inserted into the database.  I know OUTPUT can be used and we can call INSERTED.[ColumnName] to grab the values that were inserted.  Can these values be set to a variable of some kind or given an alias?  I do not want to use a TEMP table because I wish to use variables if possible.

It would be nice for the solution to work when the PK is or is not an identity column.

**EDIT:
Contacts.PhoneNumberID is a foreign key to PhoneNumber.ID
I want to do both insert statements back to back and I need the ID from PhoneNumber to use for the Contacts.PhoneNumberID**

**EDIT:
[PhoneNumber].[ID] has a default specified in the database, that is how the ID is being set**

**Here is what I am looking for:**

```
INSERT INTO [PhoneNumber] (Number) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.Number 
VALUES ('555-555-5555') 

INSERT INTO [Contacts] (Name,PhoneNumberID) 
VALUES ('SomeName', {ID From previous insert})
```

**Can we some how alias the insert statement to say:**

```
INSERT INTO [PhoneNumber] (Number) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.Number 
VALUES ('555-555-5555') as A
```

I know we cannot actually Alias an insert statement as done above, I am looking for the proper way to do this.

**Then you could do this:**

```
INSERT INTO [Contacts] (Name,PhoneNumberID) 
VALUES ('SomeName', A.ID)
```

**I am going for a final result of something similar to this:**

```
INSERT INTO [PhoneNumber] (Number) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.Number 
VALUES ('555-555-5555') as A

INSERT INTO [Contacts] (Name,PhoneNumberID) 
VALUES ('SomeName', A.ID)
```

**Reason I am trying to do this:**

I wish to put both insert statements in a transaction block, if one of them fails then I can rollback and not commit anything.

Comment: I don't understand your question or what you are trying to do here. What does an alias have to do with anything? If you want multiple statements to be part of a transaction you simply add both statements inside the transaction. The best approach would be to wrap all that inside a try/catch block.

Comment: Apologies.  I added an edit as to why I am trying to do this.  It is all based on foreign keys and I need the PK from the first table to insert into the second table

Comment: I know you mentioned trying to solve this without a `TEMP` table, however, [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10999467/3854195) using a table variable would work the way you've described.

Comment: Thank you Morpheus!  I did see that example and am hoping it can be done without a TEMP table

Comment: How is [PhoneNumber].[ID] getting a value if it is not an Identity?

Comment: There could be a default set for the [PhoneNumber].[ID] .  I will update the question.  Apologies for not specifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you need to use IDENT_CURRENT('your_table) function. It returns the last IDENTITY value produced in a table, regardless of the connection that created the value, and regardless of the scope of the statement that produced the value.
IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session; it is limited to a specified table. IDENT_CURRENT returns the identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.
So your code will look like this:

```
Declare @last_ident numeric(38,0)
INSERT INTO [PhoneNumber] (Number) 
VALUES ('555-555-5555') 

SELECT @last_ident = IDENT_CURRENT('PhoneNumber')

INSERT INTO [Contacts] (Name,PhoneNumberID) 
VALUES ('SomeName', @last_ident)
```

More information you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx)

EDIT:

If you need to get non Identity field you should use OUTPUT then

```
Declare @tbl table(ID int)
INSERT INTO [PhoneNumber] (Number) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @tbl
VALUES ('555-555-5555') 

Declare @id int
select @id = ID from @tbl

INSERT INTO [Contacts] (Name,PhoneNumberID) 
VALUES ('SomeName',@id)
```

Comment: This is close, but it seems to only work if the PK is an Identity Column

Comment: PhoneNumber.ID is my PK.  It work's great when ID is an Identity column, but if it is not then it just returns null.  I revised my question above to state that I would like the possible answer to work when the PK is and is not an identity column.  It's looking like a temp table is really the only way.

Comment: Instead of using #temp you can declare table variable DECLARE @tbl(PHONEID int) and then use your OUTPUT to collect result Inserted.ID

Comment: Ah ha! This is almost exactly what I wanted!  I didn't want to use a temp table because its such a small non complex amount of data I am selecting back

Comment: I will mark your question as answered if you can fix the minor syntax error you have.  Declare @tbl(ID int) should be Declare @tbl table(ID int)

Comment: where is that problem?

Comment: Just edited my comment.  Thanks a million for your answer :)

Comment: My pleasure - happy coding :-)

Comment: @user3329760 My comment on your question was a suggestion to use a table variable and I provided a link to an example.  ;)

Comment: Morpheus I'm so sorry, you are 100% correct! Not sure how I missed that one >_<

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest inserted from `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.
So your code could look like that:

```
DECLARE @id AS INT;
INSERT INTO [PhoneNumber] (Number) 
VALUES ('555-555-5555')

SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO [Contacts] (Name,PhoneNumberID)
VALUES ('SomeName', @id)
```

For `DECLARE @id AS INT;` you need to change the type of the variable to fit the data type PhoneNumberID column

Comment: Would SCOPE_IDENTITY() work with multiple keys if present?

Comment: @user3329760 `SCOPE_IDENTITY`works only on a `IDENTITY` column. Therefore, it can only work on a single column key (the identity field must be the primary key)

Comment: Thank you Thomas.  I've been going around and around on this one.  I know about selecting @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY(), but as stated that's only for identity columns.  Aside from a TEMP table I don't think there is any way to achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: @user3329760 **Attention:** `SCOPE_IDENTITY`can lead to problems in concurrent situations. Better to use `OUTPUT`. Please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31238742/2504785

Comment: These are two differents thing, SCOPE_IDENTITY only return the last inserted identity whereas OUTPUT will give you all the inserted data.

Comment: Sorry @SeanLange this comment was for SQLPolice

Comment: @SeanLange Please read here. `SCOPE_IDENTITY`is not really safe. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/24/sql-server-2008-scope_identity-bug-with-multi-processor-parallel-plan-and-solution/

Comment: @SQLPolice, after reading the mentioned article, this is only valid for SQL Server 2008, the bug has been fixed for SQL Server 2008R2. Please read this article : [scope-identity-returning-incorrect-value-fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562917/scope-identity-returning-incorrect-value-fixed)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Sequence](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-sequence-basics/).

```sql
Declare @newId int = NEXT VALUE FOR [PhoneNumber_Seq];
Insert into [PhoneNumber] (ID, Number)
values(@newId, '555-555-55555')

INSERT INTO [Contacts] (Name,PhoneNumberID)
VALUES ('SomeName', @newId)
```